# Filtering and binding xml data to gridview in Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq

I got a web application which contains a XML file for storing user data.I want to display entered data in grid view for that specific user only based on 'txtEmpid.Text'. I think the issue is with string reader. But I can't seem to figure out what as I am new to asp.net and this code gives me blank page.
Thanks for help

My XML file:

```
-<SkillSet>

    -<SkillSets>

    <Employee_ID>1</Employee_ID>

    <Employee_Name>abc</Employee_Name>

    <PL_Name>xyz</PL_Name>

    <Skill_Name1>C# with Asp.NET</Skill_Name1>

    <Skill_Type1>Programming</Skill_Type1>

    <Skill_Proficiency1>Beginner</Skill_Proficiency1>

    <Experience1>1</Experience1>

    <Skill_Name2>FL Studio</Skill_Name2>

    <Skill_Type2>Others</Skill_Type2>

    <Skill_Proficiency2>Intermediate</Skill_Proficiency2>

    <Experience2>2</Experience2>

    <Skill_Name3>ms word</Skill_Name3>

    <Skill_Type3>others</Skill_Type3>

    <Skill_Proficiency3>Advance</Skill_Proficiency3>

    <Experience3>3</Experience3>

    <Skill_Name4>Camtasia</Skill_Name4>

    <Skill_Type4>Others</Skill_Type4>

    <Skill_Proficiency4>Professional</Skill_Proficiency4>

    <Experience4>4</Experience4>

    <Skill_Name5>MS excel</Skill_Name5>

    <Skill_Type5>Programming</Skill_Type5>

    <Skill_Proficiency5>Beginner</Skill_Proficiency5>

    <Experience5>5</Experience5>

    <Comments>fgfdgdf</Comments>

    </SkillSets>

    </SkillSet>
```

and here is my C# file that has logic to bind data :

```
 private void BindGrid()
{
    try {

        var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/SkillSet.xml"));
        var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
        var result = str.Elements("SkillSets").
        Where(x => x.Element("Employee_ID").Value.Equals(txtEmpid.Text)).ToList();

        StringReader theReader = new StringReader(result.ToString());

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(theReader);
        if (ds != null && ds.HasChanges())
        {
            grdxml.DataSource = ds;
            grdxml.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {

            grdxml.DataBind();

        }
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        lblerror.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    string filePath = "Complete path where you saved the XML file";     
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml(filePath);    
    var skillSets = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
    var query = from skillset in skillSets
                where skillset.Field<string>("Employee_ID") == "1" // here you can get value from text box etc.
                select skillset;
    grdxml.DataSource = query.ToList();
    grdxml.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
But where is the logic to show only those records for that specific employee (the xml file would consist record for hundreds of employees, the displayed record should be for that specific employee)

Answer (score 0):

Your LINQ query is good. The problem in your code is here:

```
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(result.ToString());
ds.ReadXml(theReader);
```

You're using `result.ToString()`, and the `ToString()` representation of a List of XElements is nothing you can read as XML. In fact, calling `ToString()` will result in this

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]"
```

And as you can see, that's not XML

For your code to work, try something like this:

```
 try {

     var xmlStr = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/SkillSet.xml"));
     var str = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
     var result = str.Elements("SkillSets").
     Where(x => x.Element("Employee_ID").Value.Equals(txtEmpid.Text)).ToList();

     grdxml.DataSource = result.ToList();
     grdxml.DataBind();
 }  
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    lblerror.Text = ex.ToString();
 }
```

Also, remove the slashes on your XML

Comment: What do you mean by slashes?
but as it is, it doesn't seem to work..
but it works when I simply call all data from xml file to be binded to grid
here is the code:
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Employees.xml"));

            if (ds != null && ds.HasChanges())
            {

                grdxml.DataSource = ds;

                grdxml.DataBind();

            }
            else
            {

                grdxml.DataBind();

            }

Comment: @panman Slashes are "-" (you've some in your XML example). That second example (the one in comment) works because the argument you pass to ReadXml is a valid XML string. In your original example, it doesn't work cause the argument you pass is the result of calling "ToString()" on a List<XElement> (which is not a valid XML string). Your first code throwns an Exception.
I don't see the problem in the code I gave to you. Are you having some exception?